# Zend Framework: Application.ini what does resources.view[] = do?

Tags: zend-framework

i am wondering what does adding ...

```
resources.view[] =
```

... init `application.ini` actually do?

i know it allows me to access the view from bootstrap by

```
$this->bootstrap('view');
$view = $this->getResource('view');
```

but i wonder how does zf know `resources.view` = zend view? i guess doing that and accessing `$view` by `getResource('view')` will create a view initialized using the zend view plugin?

if i dont add the line `resources.view[] =` my app still has a zend view right? so why is that line required, just to get the view resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That line triggers bootstrapping of the View resource, see:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.view

it allows you to set a load of options (doctype, encoding etc.) via. the application.ini.

Without that line you will still have a view yes, as the viewRenderer will create a View object on demand when it is first required.

Comment: i am actually wondering if ZF is "hardcoded" to recognize that as telling it to trigger the bootstrapping the view resource, cos if i do something like `resources.myresource[] = ` it will not do anything right?

Comment: It'll map what's in the ini file to the appropriate resource class, so view[] will map to Zend_Application_Resource_View. I would imagine using a non-existent thing like myresource will error unless you create an equivalent class yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The :

```
resources.view[] =
```

in ini file is equal to php's empty array:

```
array(
    'resources' => array(
         'view' => array()  // pass empty array of the view options
    )
)
```

The Bootstrap checks whether the resources array is null,
so if you pass an empty array, **you pass no options**, but the comparison result is not null,
which results in running the view resource, but without any options.

To have the same effect, you could do:

```
resources.view.enabled = 1
```

But this sends option `enabled` to the view resource.