# Zend navigation renderMenu in view

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I'm using Zend Navigation to create my menus. When I use `$this->navigation( )` in my layout script, the menu gets rendered perfectly. But when I try to render the same menu with the same code in a view script, nothing gets rendered.

This is the code I use in the bootstrap to initiate Zend_Navigation and attach it to the layout script:

```
protected function _initNavigation( )
{
    $this->bootstrap( 'layout' );
    $layout = $this->getResource( 'layout' );

    $view = $layout->getView( );
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml( APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav' );
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation( $config );

    $view->navigation( $navigation );
    $view->addHelperPath( 'App/View/Helper/Navigation', 'App_View_Helper' );
}
```

I've been working on this problem for a while, and figured out that I needed to add the following code to my bootstrap:

```
protected function initView( ) { }
```

But I'm wondering why I need to place this useless piece of code. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317129/zend-framework-application-ini-what-does-resources-view-do) topic, I already bootstrap the view resource in my application.ini, by using the following lines:

```
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views"
resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can remove resources.view from ini with same effect as with empty initView() in bootstrap: view will not be bootstrapped

i think i have guess what is going on. where are you configure your navigation?

upd: Why do you using such a strange way to get view instance?

```
protected function _initNavigation( )
{
    $this->bootstrap( 'view' );
    $view = $this->getResource( 'view' );
    ///...
}
```

replace your method with

```
protected function _initNavigationPages( )
{
    $this->bootstrap( 'navigation' );
    $navigation = $this->getResource( 'navigation' );

    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml( APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav' );
    $navigation->addPages($config);
}
```

add to config "**resources.navigation.storage.registry = true**" if you want it to be registered in Zend_Registry under 'Zend_Navigation' key or "**resources.navigation[] =**" to store in view helper

view helper path/prefix setup move to view configuraton

Comment: I want the exact opposite: remove the initView method from the bootstrap and only keep the resources.view in the application.ini. Unfortunately, this doens't work and I'd like to know why. Appended bootstrapping code to my first post.

Comment: you can move your pages config to application.ini and remove _initNavigation method